# If $0\le f_n\to f$ a.e.where $\Vert f_n \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} = \Vert f \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}=1$ then $\int_Af_n\to\int_Af$ uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ a measurable set. Let $g_n=\vert f_n-f \vert - \vert f_n\vert + \vert f \vert $. Then $\vert g_n \vert\le2 \vert f\vert$ and $2\vert f\vert\in L^1(A)$. Dominated convergence implies $\int_A g_n\to0$. This means $(\int_A\vert f_n-f\vert)-\int_A f_n+\int_A f\to 0.$ I want to show the term in parenthesis goes to $0$ (this is enough to prove the claim). It would help if the other terms cancel out but I am not sure how to show $\int_A f_n\to \int_Af$. Fatou implies $\int_A f\le \lim\int_Af_n$. How can I show the reverse inequality if it's not given that $f_n$ is monotonic?

Comment: what is uniform convergence of a sequence of  real numbers?

Comment: Note you have $f\ge0$ a.e..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
Your arguments with $A = \R$ show already
\begin{equation*}
 (\int_\R |f_n - f|) - \int_\R f_n + \int_\R f \to 0.
\end{equation*}
Since you integrate over all of $\R$, the last two terms cancel each other.
This yields
\begin{equation*}
 \int_\R |f_n - f| \to 0.
\end{equation*}
This gives for all $A \subset \R$
\begin{equation*}
 \int_A |f_n - f| \to 0.
\end{equation*}